# three.js look at mouse. Working, but why?

Tags: three.js, geometry

I'm sure there is something simple, yet critical missing in my three.js fundamentals.

I have an eyeball always looking at the user's mouse cursor. I have it working based on a post by mr. doob, but I'm not exactly sure why/how it's working. Can someone please explain to me the math behind converting the screen coords to a scene space position. Below is my working example. I understand normalizing the mouse position, but then why do we (* 2-1), and -(* 2 + 1)?

```
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
    var mouse3D = new THREE.Vector3(
        ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1,
        - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1,
        0.5 );

    pupil.lookAt(mouse3D);
})
```

TIA for your explanations! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default 3D space runs from -1 to 1 along X, Y, and Z, and is centered at (0,0,0).

That code:

1. Converts X to the range [0,1], meaning the left edge corresponds to 0 and the right edge corresponds to 1 (`( event.clientX / window.innerWidth )`)
2. Then scales X to [0,2] (`* 2`)
3. Then shifts it to the range [-1,1] (`- 1`)
4. Converts Y to the range [-1,0], meaning the top edge corresponds to 0 and the bottom edge corresponds to -1 (`-( event.clientY / window.innerHeight )`)
5. Then scales Y to [-2,0] (`* 2`)
6. Then shifts it to the range [-1,1] (`+ 1`)
7. Uses a constant Z of 0.5 (within the range [-1,1]), since this is a 2D function.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth breakdown! This makes perfect sense now.